# How can I limit a users permission to a single service (databricks) in Azure portal?

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory

I'm wondering how I can limit a user's permission to a single service in Azure.

Specifically I want a user to be able to login to the portal and only have access to databricks and no other services.

Comment: You could use [RBAC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-portal) to do it. Just add the user in the `Access control (IAM)` in your databrick in the portal.

Comment: Yes this seems the way to go, thanks!

Comment: I don't think RBAC is the right answer for this. IMHO, it should be done through policies: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-policy/azure-policy-introduction as RBAC is for the resources and Azure Policies are for the resource types (and other things like locations etc).

Comment: I'll look into it, I think you might be correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add the user as a role in your `databrick` in the portal(**Access control (IAM)** -> **ADD**) and remove his role in the **Access control (IAM)** in the `subscription`.

For more details, refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-portal).